# Software to identify or reverse engineer patterns from encoded / decoded data

Tags: pattern-recognition, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a CSV file that contains encoded date data. I have no idea how the data was encoded, but you can look at the data and see an obvious pattern which means it was probably some sort of custom programming.

Regardless, I have a CSV file with several thousand encoded strings and their decoded values.

For example:

> "bj9sqvGTSVV34g","2014-01-01"
> "bj9sqvjOiGSgyw","2014-01-02"
> "bj9sqsV2dcIRhg","2014-01-03"
> "bj9squuZ2ceE/w","2014-01-04"

Without getting to far into the weeds, there are some very obvious patterns in the data to predict the first part of the encoded string. The second part is a mystery.

Since i have so many of these already encoded/decoded, is there any software or process that can analyze this type of data in order to analyze the row data and figure out some sort of sequence to the pattern?

Thanks!